# ExtJS REST proxy appending all model properties to query string on PUT method

Tags: json, rest, extjs, sencha-touch

When I call **mystore.sync()** in Sencha Touch 2.3.1, ExtJS appends to the defined proxy URL all properties of my model class. For instance, it sends a PUT method to the server like: **myserver/restapi/area/students?prop1=AAA&prop2=BBB&prop3=CCC&prop4=DDD&prop5=EEE**

I think this behavior is awkward and it is duplicating the request size because the JSON object has already inserted inside the request body:

**Request header =**
Content-Type: application/json

**Request body =**
{"Id":"1","Prop1":"AAA","Prop2":"BBB","Prop3":"CCC","Prop4":"DDD","Prop5":"EEE"}

So, imagine if I have a lot of string properties with a big size... It could reach the URL size limit...

Looking for solutions, I tried to change the value of **appendId** property to **false** in the REST proxy, but it has just removed one parameter (idProperty) of this URL...

Does someone knows, how can I change it? Is it a default behavior?

My code sample.

I have the store:

```
Ext.define('MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'MyModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            appendId: false, //I tried to turn it to false to it doesn't change my URL
            url: 'http://myserver/restapi/area/students
        }
    }
});
```

And the model class:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'Id',
            'Prop1',
            'Prop2',
            'Prop3',
            'Prop4',
            'Prop5'
        ],
        idProperty: [
            'Id'
        ]
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Appending properties to the URL on a PUT request is not default behavior. Do you have any overrides on the `Ext.data.proxy.Rest` or `Ext.Ajax` objects? Have you tried reproducing this problem with a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com)?

Comment: I just overrired Ext.data.Store, but I merely added some custom events and nothing else...
Now, I solved the trouble putting the proxy inside the model class and It worked fine to me.

Comment: I have discovered the problem. I was using the method "setExtraParam" to the proxy. So, now I realize that the proxy will always send theses parameters on any request. I used the extraParams because my rest API expect some params to process the collection's return.